# Hyper-V Manager is missing my running Instances of VMs

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I have two Linux VMs on my local PC that are running, but they are no longer visible from the Hyper-V manager. They are used to cross-compile programs using Linux toolchains.

I can connect to them in WinSCP and the compiler works, but they are missing from the Hyper-V manager. Anyone know of a way to rebuild the list of VMs, or some other way to display these in Hyper- V? This might be due to a storage cleanup that I did for the hard drive.

Comment: I suggest close running machines, then close Hyper-V (which may then tell you machines are running). That is close all you can, then restart the host and see if the machines now show up. You should look in your machine folder and make sure the machines are there before you start.  You may even wish to make a backup of them.

Comment: Thanks. I am not able to log into the machines to close them. I typically use Hyper-V to start them and stop them. When Windows restarts it remembers the state of each VM and will start the ones that were running. I can work around this for now using WinSCP. This might be due to a security setting that changed with a recent update.

Comment: So then try using your workaround to restart the Host Machine as suggested. This forces a restart of Hyper-V which may help

Comment: Have you tried to restart virtual machine management service on effected host? Will these VMs occur? If it still doesn't work, you might try to rename VM with PowerShell and then restart virtual machine management service and see if VMs can occur.

Comment: Thanks. I got it resolved, by using this command MOFCOMP %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsVirtualization.V2.mof

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running a command to "restoring the Hyper-V WMI registration", ref: https://www.normanbauer.com/2017/07/04/an-error-occurred-while-attempting-to-connect-to-a-hyper-v-server/

Basically, run this command as admin: MOFCOMP %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsVirtualization.V2.mof